# Typescript unknown extends T deferred type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw this code in a library code, my confusion is around `unknown extends CustomTypes[K]`, my understanding is this is a deferred type and unknown is always assignable to CustomTypes[K], so my question is how this type is actually used, particularly in which case it resolve to false. Some example can be helpful.

```
/**
 * Extendable Custom Types Interface
 */

type ExtendableTypes =
  | 'Editor'
  | 'Element'
  | 'Text'

export interface CustomTypes {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

export type ExtendedType<
  K extends ExtendableTypes,
  B
> = unknown extends CustomTypes[K] ? B : CustomTypes[K]
```

Comment: I think they left it for future plans.

Comment: @bogdanoff In TS 3.0 there is an example of this but don't have much explanation for it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably supposed to augment the interface `CustomType` through [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces). When multiple interfaces of the same name exist, they are merged together.

```
// declared somewhere in the library
export interface CustomTypes {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

// declared somewhere in your code
export interface CustomTypes {
    Editor: number
}
```

The type of the property `Editor` in `CustomTypes` is now `number` instead of `unknown`.

`ExtendedType` checks if a property's type was augmented and returns the new type.

```
type Result1 = ExtendedType<'Editor', string>
//   ^? Result1: number
```

Passing `'Editor'` and `string` to `ExtendedType` will return `number` now.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJgQwEYBsIBVwQDOUAvALABQUUAPlAOQwoCWwA9gE72XV2M4BbZMG5VaDXBASjKUsJ2BRmSRBwBmaAMbQAwgFdC7AfkjEA3jygBtANYQQALiiGOygOYBdJ3qQ2kbAHckSgBfSlk4eQ5FUEhYBGQUCBQTCAAeSwBpKClEVGJ4PPRsPAJCABpLACFKAD5SKB8-QKQchPyofUM2YzKrTI8oAH4oKqgnLqNUwn6PcIo5BSUVCHUtXQMpsqgLMWomVk4nJD0BDFXQ+djoACUiPSxgAEYGwsTk1LTGFnYucudgK4kG5apQAPRg6hQAB6IzuhAez2Op3OHCAA)

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused on how `unknown extends T` is to check if T is augmented, seems contradict to what `unknown` and `extends` normally mean.

Comment: We know that everything extends `unknown`. So `T extends unknown` would not make sense as this is true for every `T`. But `unknown` only extends `unknown`, which means that `unknown extends T` is only true if `T` is `unknown`.